# Fix images into a border (CSS)

Tags: html, image, css, border

**//EDIT:** Updated the Pen, so everybody can see the solution! [Click here](http://codepen.io/Voakie/pen/obJgGb).

What i want is simple (in my opinion). I want to make an Image that when you hover your mouse above, will get zoomed in but won't get bigger. I tried this in a Pen, here is the link: [Click here](http://codepen.io/Voakie/pen/obJgGb)

Here the CSS i used for the Image:

```
.image {
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.image:hover {
  width: 120px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

(Only made the "get bigger" animation, due to the fact that i don't know how to do this "border" thing)

An example is the button, but he still grows a bit to the top, I guess that's the same issue i have with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to change your code a bit but it is possible. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vffqz7ca/) to see your example edited to work.

Basically you put the image in a div and set the image you want zoomed in as the background image, then zoom the background image on hover

```
div.horizontalboxes:hover { background-size: 200px 150%; }
```

Simple as that.

Hope you found this answer helpful, if you have any more questions feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Excactly what I wanted! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: One question i just realized i got:

    `width: 100%;`

How does that work? Does it fill 100% of the width available in the span?

Comment: The way the above currently works is uses a div, which is similar but different than a span. The way you used it in your example, the "div.horizontalboxes" class doesn't even need to be in the CSS as it formats the div but since the div is in the span it just fits to the span. You can just set how big you want your span to be and then put the div with the image you want zoomed in and it will fit to the span if all goes well. But to answer your question, width: 100%; fills 100% of the space that it has available. Check out this page for more info http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

check this fiddle..isthis what you need?

consider the following example

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>  
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>
</div>
```

and the css

```
 .wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper img {
  margin: 4% 0;
  height: 92%;
  width: auto;
}

.wrapper img:hover {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/65bpLp9y/

Answer (score 1):

Try with the css `transform` property

```
.image:hover {
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```